# How to remove string containing dates

Tags: r

I am cleaning a dataset that only has one column.

```r
# 57 OK ZE für PZR rausgeschraubt
# 58 next
# 59 K3/ET
# 60 15.11.21 Es wurde in der heutigen Dentalhygienesitzung folgende Hilfsmittel verwendet:
# 61 UK:
# 62 -PSI, SBI, API
# 63 -Schall
```

I need to remove every row which contains different dates in character format, such as row 60: `15.11.21 Es wurde in der heutigen...`. I can't remove all numbers, because I need them later.

I tried

```r
behandlungsdoku_clean[is.na(strptime(behandlungsdoku_clean$Aufzeichnungen,
                                     format="%d-%m-%Y")),]
```

and

```r
behandlungsdoku_clean1 <- behandlungsdoku_clean[grep("%d.%m.%Y",
                                                behandlungsdoku_clean$Aufzeichnungen,
                                                invert= TRUE),]
```

but it is not working for characters.

Comment: Are all dates in the dd.mm.yy format, or can they also be for example dd/mm/yy, dd/mm/yyyy...?

Comment: All dates are in the dd.mm.yy format.

Comment: I also tried `Datum <- regexpr(behandlungsdoku_clean, "/\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\/" )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~data,
  "OK ZE für PZR rausgeschraubt",
  "next",
  "K3/ET",
  "15.11.21 Es wurde in der heutigen Dentalhygienesitzung folgende Hilfsmittel verwendet:",
  "UK:",
  "-PSI, SBI, API",
  "-Schall"
)

# Rows with dates
df2 <- df |> filter(str_detect(data, "(\\d{2}\\.){2}\\d{2}"))
df2
#> # A tibble: 1 × 1
#>   data                                                                          
#>   <chr>                                                                         
#> 1 15.11.21 Es wurde in der heutigen Dentalhygienesitzung folgende Hilfsmittel v…

# Negate to get rows without dates
df3 <- df |> filter(!str_detect(data, "(\\d{2}\\.){2}\\d{2}"))
df3
#> # A tibble: 6 × 1
#>   data                        
#>   <chr>                       
#> 1 OK ZE für PZR rausgeschraubt
#> 2 next                        
#> 3 K3/ET                       
#> 4 UK:                         
#> 5 -PSI, SBI, API              
#> 6 -Schall
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>